# Stop Scrolling list on Touch

Tags: android, scroll

How to stop scrolling while touching on the view?
I am using a **alert dialog box** , inside that dynamically data is adding.But on clicking on the view it does not stop scrolling.So i feel difficult to select an item.
Can anyone help
 **No Listview is used**

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
YourList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
}
});
```

Comment: But i am not using any listview.Iam using a Alert dialog box.So only custom layout for dialog is using.There is no list view.Data is dynamically passing to create the list.

Comment: i think for doing that you should use a custom dialog with a list in it so you can handle onTouch event and disable scrolling in your dialog , i afraid that alertdialog have such an ability to disable scrolling,if you found an alternative i will be glad to hear that

Comment: i used the above code with alert dialog variable but i didnt find any difference